# Running IIS and Confluence both on port 80 (multiple IP addresses)

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, iis-7, ip-address, confluence

I'm running Windows Server 2008 with IIS and Confluence. The server has two ip addresses setup at Network Settings.

Confluence is setup to use the second IP address. Both IIS and Confluence seem to startup fine (no errors in logs). However I can't reach Confluence. As soon as I set the port to 8090 *i can* see Confluence.

**Is it possible to use two IP addresses on your server like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Make sure that all sites on the server are bound to specific IP addresses, that includes your default site. In my example on a Windows Media Services server:

[image]

Check to see what is listening on port 80 for that IP address using `netstat -abn` to make sure that nothing else is causing interference.

Comment: I did this, and I also checked using `netstat` that my server is running on port 80. I can reach my second server (not IIS) locally through http://ipaddress/ however from my home pc i can't reach the server. The firewall is open on all IP addresses (port 80) and I can also ping the server, but I can't reach port 80 on the second IP from home...